# how to combine combo box contents in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this, birthday selection which is in 3 combobox, 1 for month, 1 for day and 1 for year.
But my database table has only this birthday attribute(no year, month or day). 
How can I combine the items that are selected in those 3 combo boxes so that they would be fitting in the birthday column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the items in your combobox are strings, you could do something like this:

```
Dim Day As Integer = Integer.Parse(ComboBoxDay.SelectedItem.ToString())
Dim Month As Integer = Integer.Parse(ComboBoxMonth.SelectedItem.ToString())
Dim Year As Integer = Integer.Parse(ComboBoxYear.SelectedItem.ToString())

Dim MyDate As New DateTime(Year, Month, Day)
```

Comment: thans user225269. And... are you using combobox for an special reason? you may want to take a look at DateTimePicker or MonthCalendar controls...? :-)